# How to calculate or get ROWSPERSTRIP, STRIPBYTECOUNTS, STRIPOFFSETS values from bitmap for tiff conversion in C#

Tags: c#, bitmap, libtiff

Converting the image to tiff image with properties. Using bitmap object converting image to tiff. In bitmap object i am not able to find the values like STRIPOFFSETS, ROWSPERSTRIP, STRIPBYTECOUNTS. 
Please help me , how to get or calcualte these values from bitmap object.

Actually i am using below code to convert tiff image from bitmap.

Please help how to get or calculate these values from bitmap object.

```
public static void GetTiffImage(string filepath)
{
    try
    {
        using (Bitmap bmp= new Bitmap(filepath))
        {
            using (Tiff tif = Tiff.Open(filename,'w'))
            {
                if (tif == null)
                    return null;          
                    tif.SetField(TiffTag.ORIENTATION, Orientation.TOPLEFT);
                    tif.SetField(TiffTag.SAMPLESPERPIXEL, 1);
                    tif.SetField(TiffTag.IMAGEWIDTH, bmp.Width); 
           //Please help how to get these below values from bitmap
                    tif.SetField(TiffTag.STRIPOFFSETS, ?);
                    tif.SetField(TiffTag.ROWSPERSTRIP, ?);
                    tif.SetField(TiffTag.STRIPBYTECOUNTS, ?);             
                }
            }

            ............................
            .....................
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`ROWSPERSTRIP` will be the image height.

`STRIPBYTECOUNTS` will be the *image height* * *width* * *colour-depth*, where *colour depth* is in bytes, so a typical 1 byte 0-255 range per each colour will be 3 bytes.